# Find indices of large array if it contains values in smaller array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Is there a fast `numpy` function for returning a list of indices in a larger array where it matches values from a smaller array? Smaller array is ~ 30M values and larger is 800M so I want to avoid a for-loop of `numpy.where` calls.

The problem with searchsorted is that it will return results even when their is not an exact match, it just gives the closest index, but I only want indices where there are exact matches

instead of this:

```
>>> a = array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> b = array([2,4,7])
>>> searchsorted(a,b)
array([1, 3, 5])
```

I would want this:

```
>>> a = array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> b = array([2,4,7])
>>> SOMEFUNCTION(a,b)
array([1, 3])
```

EDIT: the set of values in both the smaller and larger arrays are always unique and sorted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to find those elements of `a` which are in `b`.
To find the index, use one call to [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [34]: a = array([1,2,3,4,5])

In [35]: b = array([2,4,7])

In [36]: np.in1d(a, b)
Out[38]: array([False,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)

In [39]: np.where(np.in1d(a, b))
Out[39]: (array([1, 3]),)
```

Because `a` and `b` are already sorted, you could use

```
In [57]: np.searchsorted(b, a, side='right') != np.searchsorted(b, a, side='left')
Out[57]: array([False,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

instead of `np.in1d(a, b)`. For large `a` and `b`, using `searchsorted` may be faster:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.choice(10**7, size=10**6, replace=False)
a.sort()
b = np.random.choice(10**7, size=10**5, replace=False)
b.sort()

In [53]: %timeit np.in1d(a, b)
10 loops, best of 3: 176 ms per loop

In [54]: %timeit np.searchsorted(b, a, side='right') != np.searchsorted(b, a, side='left')
10 loops, best of 3: 106 ms per loop
```

---

[Jaime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31789187/find-indices-of-large-array-if-it-contains-values-in-smaller-array/31789252#comment51510477_31790052) and [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31790052/190597) have suggested some significant improvements on the method shown above. Here is some code which tests that the methods all return the same result, followed by some benchmarks:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.choice(10**7, size=10**6, replace=False)
a.sort()
b = np.random.choice(10**7, size=10**5, replace=False)
b.sort()

def using_searchsorted(a, b):
    return (np.where(np.searchsorted(b, a, side='right') 
                     != np.searchsorted(b, a, side='left')))[0]

def using_in1d(a, b):
    return np.where(np.in1d(a, b))[0]

def using_searchsorted_divakar(a, b):
    idx1 = np.searchsorted(a,b,'left')
    idx2 = np.searchsorted(a,b,'right')
    out = idx1[idx1 != idx2]
    return out

def using_jaime_mask(haystack, needle):
    idx = np.searchsorted(haystack, needle)
    mask = idx < haystack.size
    mask[mask] = haystack[idx[mask]] == needle[mask]
    idx = idx[mask]
    return idx

expected = using_searchsorted(a, b)
for func in (using_in1d, using_searchsorted_divakar, using_jaime_mask):
    result = func(a, b)
    assert np.allclose(expected, result)
```

---

```
In [29]: %timeit using_jaime_mask(a, b)
100 loops, best of 3: 13 ms per loop

In [28]: %timeit using_searchsorted_divakar(a, b)
10 loops, best of 3: 21.7 ms per loop

In [26]: %timeit using_searchsorted(a, b)
10 loops, best of 3: 109 ms per loop

In [27]: %timeit using_in1d(a, b)
10 loops, best of 3: 173 ms per loop
```

Comment: Smart stuff with the left-right use of searchsorted! Guess you need to index into `np.searchsorted(b, a, side='left')` with the mask though to get the actual indices.

Comment: You would still need to use `np.where` to get the indices with respect to `a`.

Comment: I meant something like : `idx1 = np.searchsorted(a,b,'left');
idx2 = np.searchsorted(a,b,'right'); out = idx1[idx1 != idx2]`. Would work maybe?

Comment: @Divakar: That looks to be about 5x faster than my suggested solution (on the larger test case). Would you like to write it up?

Comment: Appreciate the motivation there! Largely inspired by your solution I must say. Just posted the solution here.

Comment: Thanks for the effort on both of you, this does just fine for me!

Answer (score 6):

The default seacrh direction with [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) is `left`. We can also search for it from the `right` direction and the ones that are same in both these set of indices would be the ones to be avoided from the indices outputted from the `left` option to get the desired output. The motivation here is same as discussed in [`@unutbu's solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31789252/3293881).

Thus, the implementation would look like this -

```
idx1 = np.searchsorted(a,b,'left')
idx2 = np.searchsorted(a,b,'right')
out = idx1[idx1 != idx2]
```

Comment: Using `searchsorted(larger, smaller)` instead of `searchsorted(smaller, larger)` and indexing `idx1` instead of using `np.where` makes this a much smarter way to do it.

Comment: You have to add extra handling, because `searchsorted` may return indices out of bounds, but a potentially quicker way of discarding non-matches, rather than re-searching with "right"... is to check if they match! `idx = np.searchsorted(haystack, needle); mask = idx < haystack.size; mask[mask] = haystack[idx[mask]] == needle[mask]; idx = idx[mask]`